# Does it help to sabotage the investigation?

Tags: indigo-prophecy

I've just started playing Fahrenheit: Indigo Prophecy and to begin with at least, you play both the murderer and the cops. Assuming that we're meant to be on the side of the murderer, does it help to play the police's part badly? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not exactly meant to be on the side of the murderer, you are kind of meant to play on all sides. Try to treat every character that you play at the moment as if it is your main character, and work by it's needs.

It's possible to, for example, miss clues at the start of the game. But that still doesn't prevent *you* from knowing who actually did it.

I played it from all sides as if I didn't know anything the character didn't know, and did everything as if the current character is my main one.